# In chef, is there a way to do something only if file A == file B?

Tags: chef-infra

I'm trying to put together a simple recipe to push an application to a node. At the moment, I have it at a point where the recipe takes a zip file, puts it onto the node and then unzips the file.

What I want to do now is:

```
//Pseudo code
if (new zip file == existing zip file)
    //do nothing
else
    delete the unzipped directory
    overwrite the existing zip file with the new one
    unzip the new file
end if
```

I'm having trouble with the part where I delete the unzipped directory. I know that chef supports not_if and only_if conditionals but I don't know how to ask the question (is file A the same as file B?)

Is this possible?

Comment: I am missing one thing here, how do you 'get' your zip archive? Is it downloaded from remote path? If so, you can use remote_file it will fire up only if file changes and chain of notifications.

Comment: The zip file is attached to the cookbook itself underneath the /files directory. I do actually use remote_file to copy the zip onto the node - that bit is working well.

The issue is with unzipping. If I unzip the new zip file the contents of the old one persist in the unzip destination directory. I need to remove all of these old files so that they can be replaced with the contents of the new zip file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using remote_file it makes everything a little bit simpler. By default file is downloaded only when it changes, so based on this you can create chain of notifications, something like shown below:

```
remote_file File.join(Chef::Config["file_cache_path"], "file.zip") do
  source   "http://url/to/archive.zip"
  notifies :run, "execute[remove old directory]", :immediately
end

execute "remove old directory" do
  command "rm /path/to/your/directory"
  action  :nothing
  notifies :run, "execute[unzip new directory],": immediately
end

execute "unzip new directory" # here you can use any combination of other resources, like unzip/7z/ark
  command "unzip #{File.join(Chef::Config["file_cache_path"], "file.zip")} /path/to/your/directory"
  action  :nothing
end
```

This solution has some caveats, for example if removal process fails, you will have to remove archive from cache to run it again.

As an alternative, you could try [ark](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/ark) cookbook, it can download and unzip archives. I am not sure if you want to add another cookbook to maintain for fairly simple task executed once.

Comment: Perfect, I'll try that out later today but this seems like exactly what I was after - thanks so much :)